# Google App Engine Java Full Text Search index doesn't store all the text

Tags: java, google-app-engine, full-text-search

I am using Google App Engine SDK 1.7.5. 
and following full text search api com.google.appengine.api.search

While creating a full text search index for a object, my index is created successfully for the object but some of the text properties that are pretty long in content doesn't get stored fully instead they get truncated and I am not able to find the reason why.
Has anyone come across this problem before